# Most common platform for Monetizing android App

Tags: android, google-play

wanted to know which are the most common options for monetizing an App on adriod.  I'm a newbie in the field and I'm doing research before I put out my first app.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/index.html

And do some research next time before asking opinion based questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to ask what are you "developers" using as your most common platform.  Yes I have done extensive research but it's always good to find out what your peers are using.  Thanks

Comment: In app purchase, ads, in app upgrades are the most common ones.And dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you. Cheers